# What's the different between consecutive if and nested if?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to Java. Here are my two codes.

1).

---

```
    if (!isCorrectGuess(guess) && !isPriorGuess(guess)){
        state += 1;
    }

    if( isCorrectGuess(guess) && !isPriorGuess(guess)){
        correctguess += guess;
    }

    if (!isPriorGuess(guess)){
        guessed += guess;
    }

    return isCorrectGuess(guess) && !isPriorGuess(guess);
```

2).

---

```
    if (!isPriorGuess(guess)){
        guessed += guess;
        if (isCorrectGuess(guess)){
            correctguess += guess;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            state += 1;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

I think they should have the same result, but it seems I am wrong. Could anyone tell my what's the difference between the two codes? Thanks!

It's my homework, the first code failed the test but the second past.

Here's my code for isCorrect and isPrior:

---

```
public boolean isCorrectGuess(char guess) {
    return guessWord.indexOf(guess) != -1;
}

public boolean isPriorGuess(char guess) {
    return guessed.indexOf(guess) != -1;
}
```

Comment: Is this Java or Javascript? (They aren't the same!) More to the point, though, do `isCorrectGuess(guess)` and `isPriorGuess(guess)` return the same value every time they are called? Do either of them have side effects that may change the value of `guess`, `state`, `correctguess`, or `guessed`?

Comment: _"but it seems I am wrong"_ -- Why do you say that?

Comment: Thanks Ted! I think it should be Java, I changed the tag.  It's my homework, I run both code, the first failed the test, but the second code passed. I will post my isCorrectGuess and isPriorGuess as well.

Comment: Also in addition to what Ted asked, do isPriorGuess or isCorrectGuess use the `guessed` or `correctguess` variables (if those are class members and not local variables?)  If so, then when in your code flow you update `guessed` or `correctguess` might change the results.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that they do.  As soon as you add `guessed += guess;` all future calls of `isPriorGuess(guess)` will return true.  In the first code, this causes a bug in your return statement because you call isPriorGuess after updating guess.

Comment: Yes, @PMV asked the critical question. I updated my answer in view of the new information; it now explains why the two cases are very different.

Comment: This can't be Java.  There is no way in Java that `guessed += guess` and `guessed.indexOf()` are both legal.  Is `guessed += guess` supposed to append an element to an array?

Comment: @ajb - It appears that `guessed` is a `String`, so `guessed += guess` is legal and so is `guessed.indexOf(guess)`.

Comment: @TedHopp somehow I didn't see the `char` and got it into my head that the guesses were integers...  thanks.

Comment: @ajb   Ted is right.  `guessed`  is a `String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is tagged `Javascript` but your question says `Java`. They are not the same at all, but my answer is the same for both languages.

Assuming that `isCorrectGuess()` and `isPriorGuess()` are [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) (behave the same each time they are called) and have no side effects, the only difference between the two cases (as far as I can tell) is the number of times and the order in which the two functions are called. The effects on the various variables and the return values seem to be identical.

**EDIT** Your editing of the question explains why the two cases are not the same. The call to `isPriorGuess()` relies on the current value of `guessed`, which changes as case 1 and case 2 execute. In particular, suppose that before either case executes, `isPriorGuess(guess)` returns `false` and `isCorrectGuess(guess)` returns true. Then in case 1, the code

```
if (!isPriorGuess(guess)){
    guessed += guess;
}
```

changes the value of `guessed` so that on subsequent calls, `isPriorGuess(guess)` will return true. In consequence, when the `return` statement is executed:

```
return isCorrectGuess(guess) && !isPriorGuess(guess);
```

the return value will always be `false` (either `isCorrectGuess(guess)` returns `false` or `isPriorGuess(guess)` will return `true`). In case 2, that doesn't happen because `isPriorGuess(guess)` is called exactly once (and `isCorrectGuess(guess)` is called 0 or 1 time, depending on the value of `isPriorGuess(guess)`).

Comment: Thanks Ted! I think it should be Java, I changed the tag.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @victor - This kind of bug is difficult to track down. One technique for avoiding it is to redesign `isPriorGuess()` and `isCorrectGuess()` to receive all the values they need as arguments, rather than relying on fields that may change between calls. That would make it apparent in case 1 that the methods are receiving different information on different calls (or, at least, `isPriorGuess()` is).

Comment: I really appreciate your patience and suggestion. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example conservative if every if condition will be evaluated and if true it's body will be executed, but in nested if if condition evaluated as true it's else won't be checked.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's questions: what's the consequence in terms of the changes to the variables and the return value?